# Auto retrieve 100 on an Invite message on Tomcat Mobicents

Tags: sip, jain-sip

I am trying to do a load tests for the call forwarding B2BUA application sample on  MSS 2.00 (Sip Servlet).
I am doing a 80 Caps on 4 Tomcat Instances on linux Redhat 2.6
The problem I am facing is that the 100 For the UAC invite is not send immediatly once recieved on MSS,
It is sent only one the 100 from the UAS returns it.

I managed to find a case on JBOSS which uses the following configuration flag

http://code.google.com/p/mobicents/source/browse/trunk/servers/sip-servlets/sip-servlets-test-suite/sipp-scenarios/performance/jboss-5-setup/mss-sip-stack-jboss.properties?r=14623

it appears to be some kind of an old bug fix

http://code.google.com/p/mobicents/issues/detail?id=1689

However, I tried to put the following entries in the mss-sip-stack.properties

```
org.mobicents.ext.java.sip.TRANSACTION_FACTORY=org.mobicents.ext.javax.sip.MobicentsTransactionFactory
org.mobicents.ext.java.sip.SIP_PROVIDER_FACTORY=org.mobicents.ext.javax.sip.MobicentsSipProviderFactory    
org.mobicents.ext.java.sip.SEND_TRYING_RIGHT_AWAY=true
```

but it didn't made a change

I tried to dig into the code and found out this:

The flag is defined in the following interface

SipStackExtension

as well as the other factories

However, The only available impelemtation was the ABSTRACT class ClusteredSipStackImpl

So what should I do inorder to enable this flag on the above configuration?

I made the test on an amd64 blade (12 cores), 
I tried both 32 Bit and 64 Bit, the result was the same.

Comment: Following this [article](http://jeanderuelle.blogspot.co.il/2010/08/introducing-jain-sip-ha-or-how-you-can.html) I understand that many JBOSS jars should be used in this process. Therefor I decided to check other alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

The flag was not usable on Tomcat, only JBoss, that is now fixed in http://code.google.com/p/sipservlets/issues/detail?id=138 and will be available in our next release 2.0.0.FINAL

Thanks
Jean